# SSRS bar chart issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, bar-chart, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to add one box and one line on x-axis. Please look at below bar chart.

[image]

I tried using stripline but I cannot set height for stripline. It goes till 100.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SSRS doesn't provide the functionality you're looking for. A stripline is the closest you can get to that, but like you said, you can't control its height. The only way you could simulate this behavior would be to use a Background Image for your stripline, but that may be more work than it's worth. It would require a lot of manual adjustment to get the image to line up on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a series to the chart using the Stock chart (under Range). In the Series Properties I would set the High value to the height desired for your line (~52 in your example).  Ideally this would come from a dataset value.

Set the Low, Open and Close values to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try two Stripe Lines.  First, create the strip line which represents the vertical value you're after.  In my case, I made one that was 50% of the graph height off of the Y-Axis.

Chart Properties:
[image: Properties]

Height of StripeLine:
[image: Actual Height]

Once the stripe line is the correct height for the chart, create a 'mask' stripe line along the X-axis that will cover the portion of the Y-axis line you want hidden.

Chart Propterites:
[image]

Width of Stripe Mask:
[image]

Using these methods, and some really clever expression writing, you should be able to make the line exactly as high, and as wide as you desire.